# Magento 1.9 - Create product custom options programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, custom

I have a php code for creating product custom options programmatically but don't know where to place this code.

`

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
require_once 'Zend/Crypt/Hmac.php';umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

function getOptions(){
    return array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Option Value 1',
            'price' =>100,
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            'sort_order' => '1'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Option Value 2',
            'price' =>100,
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            'sort_order' => '1'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Option Value 3',
            'price' =>100,
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            'sort_order' => '1'
        )
    );
}

$option = array(
    'title' => 'custom option title',
    'type' => 'radio', // could be drop_down ,checkbox , multiple
    'is_require' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'values' => getOptions()
);


$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$product_id = $obj->getIdBySku('skuid1');
$product = $obj->load($product_id);
$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance()->unsetOptions();
$product->setHasOptions(1);
$optionInstance->addOption($option);
$optionInstance->setProduct($product);
$product->save();
unset($product);
echo "Done";

$product_id = $obj->getIdBySku('skuid2');
$product = $obj->load($product_id);
$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance()->unsetOptions();
$product->setHasOptions(1);
$optionInstance->addOption($option);
$optionInstance->setProduct($product);
$product->save();
unset($product);
echo "Done";
```

`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Code looks like its a custom code outside magento as you have added Mage.php etc.

So you need to create a create_custom_options.php(as per your requirement) on your root directory of magento and place the code to that file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried but no option is displaying.Can you describe in detail? I want to create custom options for all products.

Comment: My custom options dropdown showing error in prototype.js:612 how can i solve this error?     https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/266640/57334 @Sukumar Gorai

Answer (score 0):

In the directory where all magento files and folders are placed like "app" , "downloader" , "errors" , "media" etc folders are places , create php file call createcustomoptions.php and write your code in it.

```
After it Run it through the site url like: www.example.com/createcustomoptions.php
```

where example.com will be your site url